# Text extraction from PDF file, with differents sizes and colors fonts, using PDFBOX - Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm developing a java application that extracts text from a pdf file, for this reason I use PDFBox library. I can extract most of the text from the file, but I can not extract certain words that have a larger size and a different color.
I have tried to use the method    setAverageCharTolerance of     pdfstripper class, but I have not had any results. 
I wonder if anyone knows of any way to get extract all the text from the pdf file, whether this is large or small or different colors?

Comment: Size and color do not stop pdfbox from extracting Text. Thus, the problem is something else. Please provide the pdf for analysis.

Comment: Please do also check whether copy & paste from the acrobat reader gets these words or not.